# Exception shows up in console although try...catch must prevent it

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, minimal-apis

In my minimal API I try to save entity to database. The table contains UNIQUE constraint on `license_plate` column, so `DbUpdateException` would be thrown if same license plate would be passed in. I used `try..catch` in order to handle this situation:

```cs
app.MapPost("/vehicles", (VehiclesContext db, Vehicle vehicle) =>
{
  var entity = db.Add(vehicle);
  try
  {
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Results.CreatedAtRoute("GetVehicle", new { inventoryNumber = entity.Entity.InventoryNumber }, entity.Entity);
  }
  catch (DbUpdateException)
  {
    var error = new JsonObject
    {
      ["error"] = $"Creating vehicle failed because such license plate already exists: {vehicle.LicensePlate}"
    };
    return Results.BadRequest(error);
  }
}).AddFilter<ValidationFilter<Vehicle>>();
```

However, when I pass duplicate license plate, I see this exception in console:
[image]

So, why does this exception show up in console? I tried to play with `LogLevel` for `Microsoft.AspNetCore` in `appsettings.json` (and `appsettings.Development.json` also) by changing `Warning` to `Information`, but still exceptions shows up.

Comment: This is a serious error, not just information and not even a warning. Maybe you would have to log nothing at all to not see log messages like this? Usually you want to log at least errors, right?

Comment: @topsail I'm not saying I don't want to log errors - I just don't want to see errors _which I handle in try...catch block!_

Answer (score 0):

The exception is logged prior to throwing, so you cannot stop the logging mechanism from being invoked.

However, you should be able to control output using LogLevel.

Note that the log comes from "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" not "Microsoft.AspNetCore".

Comment: I tried `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning"` and `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information"` - still error shows up. 

Answer (score 0):

> I just don't want to see errors which I handle in try...catch block!

Do you mean you don't want to see the `fail` ? Use Try-catch in minimal API?

Below is a demo, you can refer to it.

without try-catch

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () =>{
      string s = null;
      if (s == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(s), message: "parameter can't be null.");
      }}    
);    
app.Run();
```

result:

[image]

use try-catch:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () =>{     
      try
      {
          string s = null;
          if (s == null)
          {
              throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(s), message: "parameter can't be null.");
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);         
      }
  }
);
app.Run();
```

result:

[image]